# Migrate into paragraphs without parent import

Tags: 8, migrations, paragraphs

If I have a data source with some values, can I process those into a paragraph attached to a node in Drupal 8 without having to run a prior migration to create the paragraphs first (and then relying on a migration_lookup)?

Would I need some kind of process plugin (like [Import Json data into node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202474/import-json-data-into-node) uses) or can this be done out of the box with simple generic sub-process/mapping config in the YML?

Comment: This is possible, you can create a plugin that takes the data, creates and saves a paragraph Entity, and returns the paragraph id for the target id value (for the paragraph field).

Comment: @kevin I guess I’d need to maintain my own “map”? So that on updates I’d know what the new paragraph would resolve back to? (Is it a new paragraph or updating and existing item, etc).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look possible Out of the Box without another import. You could try with a contributed module like: https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_child_entity_generate